# Unable to send UDP packets while performing OTA update on the esp8266

Tags: esp8266, ota, esp

I am sending specific **UDP** packets with my **esp8266** every 5s, I have added an **OTA update** command, and added the update_progress callback aiming to send it back to my laptop, using a serial terminal I noticed that regular packets, as well as the progress packet, are not sent during the update, everything gets back after. Is the esp able to send and receive packets simultaneously?, is there any interference or the **OTA update** process causes an interruption?

*Hardware: ESP8266MOD Nodemcu*

*Software: VS code with portable Arduino 1.8.9, espcore 2.6.3*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esp8266 ArduinoOTA library has

```cpp
  WiFiUDP::stopAll();
  WiFiClient::stopAll();
```

to ensure undisturbed OTA upload

Comment: Any way to trick it to enable UDP, or sweep between TCP(for OTA) and UDP, I am using the ESP8266httpUpdate library and it disables all wifi clients except TCP, commenting that section did nothing

Comment: @AlaeddineSalem, you can try to remove the lines from the library